# Refer to data files from within C++ project

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have a C++ project with a folder structure something like so:

```
root/trunk
root/trunk/src/...        
root/trunk/include/...    
root/trunk/utils/...      <-- this has the `main` programs which are compiled
root/trunk/bin/...        compiled binaries
root/data/...             data used in the programs
```

In my source files, I sometimes refer to files included in the data subfolders. I want the paths I use to be relative paths (because I am sharing this project with someone else).

How can I ensure that the data files can always be found? Currently I use paths such as the following:

```
std::string my_data("../../../data/path/to/file.txt");
```

However, I find it difficult using this to work out where the relative path leads to, and can be messy when source files are moved. Is the a better way of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: Are the data files part of building the code?

Comment: No, they are referred to at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common method of organizing data files is to establish a "data root" folder at program startup, and then code your paths relative to that.  The data root can be automatically determined by searching (the current directory and perhaps its parent, grandparent, etc, up to the real root.) for a specially named file or directory (eg ".foo"), and overridden by an environment variable or command-line switch (eg FOO_DATA_DIR="/home/fred/bar").

For conveniance the program could change its current working directory to the data root, or alternatively you can resolve your data root relative paths programmatically in userland.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good. How should I search for that directory without having to search the whole computer?

Comment: Start looking in the current working directory, and then ascend to the ancestors to the root. (ie the program can be started in the data root dir or a subdirectory of it,  or alternatively the data dir can be specified as an env variable)

Comment: @BillCheatham Don't search, know.  This is your root; you define the structure under it.  Once you've determined the root, access the individual files with something like `myRoot / "data" / "datafile1.txt"` (supposing that `myRoot` has type `boost::filesystem::path`).

Answer (score 2):

You should not make any assumptions about what the current working directory will be when your program is run - use a more robust method to determine the location of your data files, which doesn't rely on the working directory being set to anything in particular. Test this by setting the working directory to somewhere unrelated to your program and then run it from there, e.g.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ /path/to/my/program/root/trunk/bin/my_program
```

and see if it runs OK.

Comment: I see - so the relative path isn't relative to the build location, but it's relative to the working directory at runtime?

Comment: Exactly - there is nothing to prevent someone from running your program from any directory they feel like. Hence the need for a more robust method for finding your data files.

Answer (score 2):

Before going any further, you want to define a delivery directory
structure; what other users will see when they install your code.  Then,
work from that: under Windows, you can use the function
`GetModuleFileName` to find where your binary is located, and work from
that; under Unix, it's traditional to require the user to set an
environment variable, something like `MYPROJ_ROOT`, and use that as the
root of your tree.  Either way, you have a starting point; you want your
filenames relative to that, and *not* to the current working directory.
You can do this either by changing the current working directory for
your process (`SetCurrentDirectory` under Windows, `chdir` under Unix),
or (my preferred solution) by using something like `boost::filesystem` 
to build up absolute names from the name of the root.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea. How can I ensure that users do this? I'm developing using CMake under Ubuntu.

Comment: @BillCheatham Under Unix, you can't.  You create a tar file, which they unpack, and you document that they must define the environment variable to point to where they unpacked it if they want to use it.  (There are more complicated packaging tools available, which are worth looking into if your directory structure is complex, or you have a lot of users.  They still require the user to set an environment variable, however, unless you impose a root directory yourself, and hard code it into your code.)

Comment: Under Linux, you can query where `/proc/self/exe` points to. Under OSX, you're probably in the bundle, and can use Carbon to query that (`CFBundleCopyExecutableURL` and related). Dunno about other *nices, but that's majority of desktops covered, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough code in your question to see exactly what you're doing, but in the past, I've used the `__FILE__` preprocessor macro (and subsequently removed filenames/directories) to reference files which are relative to where source files are located:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=380822

Comment: That doesn't really solve the working directory problem and it doesn't work if the path to the source changes.