# how to get path to executable in C running on Windows?

Tags: c, windows

-getcwd does not return it at least when debugging with VS 2010.

-i have no access to main's arguments because of the user interface kit i'm using

so is there anything to do?

PS. please note the restrictions before tagging this as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refer to data files from within C++ project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068081/refer-to-data-files-from-within-c-project) - on Windows you probably want [GetModuleFileName](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9068458/253056).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GetModuleFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pass NULL as the first argument:

```
DWORD last_error;
DWORD result;
DWORD path_size = 1024;
char* path      = malloc(1024);

for (;;)
{
    memset(path, 0, path_size);
    result     = GetModuleFileName(0, path, path_size - 1);
    last_error = GetLastError();

    if (0 == result)
    {
        free(path);
        path = 0;
        break;
    }
    else if (result == path_size - 1)
    {
        free(path);
        /* May need to also check for ERROR_SUCCESS here if XP/2K */
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != last_error)
        {
            path = 0;
            break;
        }
        path_size = path_size * 2;
        path = malloc(path_size);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (!path)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failure: %d\n", last_error);
}
else
{
    printf("path=%s\n", path);
}
```

Comment: thanks! for some reason i thought that was C++ only. i'll try it!

Comment: it works! i get it in funny form though: it's ..\..\ from the current work directory. which is ok I guess. thanks again!

Comment: That sounds odd. It should be the full path of the executable, like `C:\Program Files\myapplication\my.exe`.

Comment: The final parameter to GetModuleFileName() is the number of elements in the array, not the size in bytes. So while it works here I wouldn't routinely use `sizeof(exe_path)` by itself.

Comment: The string returned will use the same format that was specified when the module was loaded. Therefore, the path can be a long or short file name, and can use the prefix "\\?\". For more information, see Naming a File.

Comment: @hmjd: is the first if correct? if it too long it returns copied length not including terminating null character

Comment: I was using the inner if, `ERROR_IMSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, to illustrate that point. Updating with more complete example.

Comment: Hi! Old answer, very helpful. A question: Why the `memset` at the beginning? Is it necessary? Why? If it is, why not simply use `calloc` in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Pass `NULL` as the first argument of [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx).